# Windows Form code not executing?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

Ok, I've got a weird one here.  I'm trying to make a basic tile engine using a windows form, but some of my code is just...not happening.  I'll post the chunks in question.

```
private void MapEditor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadImageList();
        FixScrollBarScales();
        cboCodeValues.Items.Clear();
        cboCodeValues.Items.Add("ENEMY");
        cboCodeValues.Items.Add("CHEST");
        cboCodeValues.Items.Add("NPC");

        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
            cboMapNumber.Items.Add(x.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0'));

        cboMapNumber.SelectedIndex = 0;
        TileMap.EditorMode = true;
        backgroundToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
    }
```

This should be called when the form loads, right?  The code dives into LoadImageList(), which contains:

```
private void LoadImageList()
{
    string filepath = Application.StartupPath + 
        @"\Content\Textures\IndoorTileSet.png";
    Bitmap tileSheet = new Bitmap(filepath);
    int tilecount = 0;
    for(int y = 0; y < tileSheet.Height / TileMap.TileHeight; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < tileSheet.Width / TileMap.TileWidth; x++)
        {
            Bitmap newBitmap = tileSheet.Clone(
                new System.Drawing.Rectangle(
                        x * TileMap.TileWidth, 
                        y * TileMap.TileHeight, 
                        TileMap.TileWidth, 
                        TileMap.TileHeight), 
                System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare);
            imgListTiles.Images.Add(newBitmap);
            string itemName = "";
            if(tilecount == 0)
                itemName = "Empty";
            if(tilecount == 1)
                itemName = "Floor";
            listTiles.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(itemName, tilecount++));
        }
    }
}
```

The bitmap loads correctly, but then the entire MapEditor_Load method just stops working.  tileCount seems to be a local variable in the debugger, and its value is 0, but the debugger never executes the breakpoint on the line which it is assigned.  I have absolutely no idea why it would do this, and it's driving me nuts.  Any help?
Oh, I put the bitmap load in a try/catch block just to see if it was handling an exception in a weird way, but I had no luck.  It's not throwing an exception.  I began having this problem immediately after replacing my IndoorTileSet with an updated version. I've tried a clean rebuild, with no success.

I read something about a person having a similar problem, who wound up having to declare something as an Instance of a class, but the post wasn't detailed enough for me to know if that's where I'm going wrong, or what I might have to declare as an Instance for it to work...or what an Instance even means, really.

Comment: As an aside, look into `Path.Combine` to ensure you don't mess up that file path.

Comment: Otherwise, if you put your breakpoint on the first line of `LoadImageList`, can you step through line by line?

Comment: I will check the patch, thanks for the suggestion.  I can step through LoadImageList, but it jumps out of the method before the lines I mentioned.  Someone else I asked about the problem mentioned that it might be an issue with 64-bit operating systems.  I'll post their suggestion below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the code in `LoadImageList`() method but I suggest you to use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) or [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) to make your application more responsive.

Comment: I'll keep the suggestion in mind, I can see how those things would be helpful.  I just can't figure out why my code would just not happen. Could this be a resource conflict that multithreading would avoid?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Bitmap tileSheet = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(filepath);
```

Comment: This didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, superficially, that my Bitmap code is throwing an FileNotFound exception, which means I've got a bad filepath.  I can handle that.  The issue of the program not actually throwing exceptions, and seeming to ignore code, is an issue with 64-bit operating systems not being able to handle exception calls in all instances.  The details, and a link to a hotfix to solve the issue, can be found at [this site](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/07/20/the-case-of-the-disappearing-onload-exception-user-mode-callback-exceptions-in-x64/).